# SQL Server : sum of 2 columns in each row display

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am using SQL Server. I have 2 columns `Passed students` and `Failed Students` in my database.

How to write a query which displays both these columns along with a third column which is `Total Students` which displays the sum of the entries in the row?

**EDIT**

It is not allowing me to ask another question.So,posting it here:

I have a hyperlink field in my gridview as below:

[Please refer comment for the code.For some reason it doesn't get posted here.]

Its basically a runId.When I click on this hyperlink I am redirected to a page called RunAnalysis.I want to access the value of the runId which was clicked in this page.

I was thinking of using query string but there is no event as far as I know that is fired on click of the hyperlink.

My question is how do I access the runId value in this page ? Can someone tell me if some event is fired so that I can send a query string.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to SUM the values? Do you want to show row wise SUM or Column wise. Please provide Input columns and expected OUTPUT in brief

Comment: What do you mean by **displays the sum of the entries in the row** can you show one example

Comment: <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText = "RunID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="RunAnalysis.aspx"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given a lot of background information so I am assuming many things in my response.

Here is a simple aggregated result set:

```
SELECT SUM(Passed) AS [Passed],SUM(Failed) AS [Failed],COUNT(*) AS [TotalStudents]
FROM dbo.Students
```

Now if there is some grouping you want to do then you would add a `GROUP BY` clause like so...

I'm creating a new column because I don't know your schema:

```
SELECT GradeLevel, SUM(Passed) AS [Passed],SUM(Failed) AS [Failed],COUNT(*) AS [TotalStudents]
FROM dbo.Students
GROUP BY GradeLevel
ORDER BY GradeLevel
```

Comment: @PayalAgarwal - If this answer helped you to solve the problem then mark it as answer by selecting the **tick mark** to the left of this answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28229299/what-are-some-good-table-ui-designs-for-a-dashboard can you please help me with this ?